# How to get specific value from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase

I have JSON, which looks like this:

```
{ '-KiJz4D0pGYE35HPP-E4': { code: '211', lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'John' } }
```

I do know that it will always look this way, ONLY one child in any case. How could I get value '211' stored under code key. Right now I have ugly code with foreach, it even works, but... Why would I use foreach at all if I know there is only one child?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That isn't JSON. You should first fix the data so it is.

Comment: "Right now I have ugly code with foreach, it even works" — Not if you have that "JSON". Maybe you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: "Why would I use foreach at all if I know there is only one child?" — Because looping over all one of the things with unknown names will give you the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 '-KiJz4D0pGYE35HPP-E4': {
  code: '211',
  lastname: 'Smith',
  firstname: 'John'
 }
};

var objKey = Object.keys(jsonObj); // return the object key

var innerObject = jsonObj[objKey]; // return the inner object

var code = innerObject.code; // return the code property value.

console.log(code);
```

Answer (score 1):

USe `Object.keys(obj)[0]` to get the first key and then you can get the key `code's` value from it like

```js
var obj = { '-KiJz4D0pGYE35HPP-E4': { code: '211', lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'John' } }
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]['code']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If

```
var data = { '-KiJz4D0pGYE35HPP-E4': { code: '211', lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'John' } };
```

Then
data[Object.keys(data)[0]] will return your inner object

```
{ code: '211', lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'John' }
```

So you easily get code value by `data[Object.keys(data)[0]].code`

Answer (score -1):

```
Object.values({ '-KiJz4D0pGYE35HPP-E4': { code: '211', lastname: 'Smith', firstname: 'John' } })[0].code;
```

Simply get the first value of the outer Object...